# Question about what snaps being sandboxed means

Tags: snap

When I install a snapcraft app the snap is sandboxed. This adds a level of safety to installing snaps, right? It means that when installed, a snap is self-contained right? so there's no way one could inadvertently install malicious software onto your computer through installing a snap right? Even if the snap is untrustworthy, once removed there is no need to worry about it since it was sandboxed from the rest of your computer-- am I understanding this right?

Thanks in advance for any help understanding :)

I'm wondering because I installed a questionable snapcraft app that wouldn't show up anywhere to launch it, and comments reported it being a fake app. So I uninstalled through the software centre. Just wanna check that's enough. And I don't need to reinstall ubuntu out of worry for malware or anything.

Comment: IN the case of snap its quite a sophisticated feature that uses kernel cgroups to sandbox the apps your installing.    In fact it can also install the core of different kernel versions so that compatibility is maintained.

Whilst I doubt that snap will entirely replace apt on ubuntu for base packages.. there is no doubt its superior for installing running solutions.    Its the ubuntu standard for installing LXD which is itself a container based system which sandboxes.. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So snaps are relatively safer than using apt, because of the sandboxing?

What is the potential for sketcky apps. Like the one I installed. There was no option to launch upon install, couldn't find it to open. Straight away removed it through software centre. 

Reviewers reported same thing about not being able to find it upon install to open, no option to launch. People were saying its a fake app, maybe malware. Worried me. Made me think are there potential risks associated with accidentally installing a random snap?

Comment: snap applications are not safer than apt about the same level.   But snap is more flexible than apt packages.

Answer (score 1):

This reference from Technopedia should provide the information you are looking for.

[image]

[reference](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/25266/sandboxing)

Comment: Thank you! And snaps are sandboxed, right? Feel reassured I don't need to worry too much about the seemingly sketchy snapcraft app I installed (and subsequently removed) then. I run the command snap list in terminal and the snap isn't listed. So I guess I don't have anything to worry about

Comment: @tmrrr No problem. If that addresses your question please consider [accepting it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) Thank you.